# Getting specific recipe posted from user that is logged in and Deleting the recipe using recipe_id - flask peewee

Tags: python, flask, peewee

I am trying to delete a recipe using recipe_id that belongs to a user_id. MY delete route is deleting all the recipes in the recipes [] I created. I am still new to flask and peewee. i would appreciate a pointers cause I am sure I doing something wrong.

```
@app.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def profile_page():
    
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    return jsonify(logged_in_as=current_user), 200
  

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])

def login():
   if request.method == 'POST' :
        
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            if not username:
                return jsonify('Missing username'), 400

            if not password:
                return jsonify('Missing password'), 400
            registered_user = Users.get(Users.username == username, Users.fullname == Users.fullname)
            password_pass =  check_password_hash(registered_user.password_harsh, password)  
            if registered_user:     
                
                if password_pass:
                    access_token = create_access_token(identity=registered_user)
                    return {"access_token": access_token} , 200
                    
            
            else: 
                return jsonify('Invalid Login Info'), 400
        
        
   return jsonify("Please provide an email and password"), 400   

@app.route('/add_recipe', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_required()
def add_recipe():
  
    
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    
    if  not request.method == 'POST':

        return jsonify('Please enter your data')

    else:
        name = request.form['name']
        description = request.form['description']
        ingredients = request.form['ingredients']
        process = request.form['process']
        poster_id = current_user
      

        new_recipe = Recipe.create(name = name, description = description, ingredients = 
        ingredients, process=process, poster_id = poster_id)
    
    return jsonify("You have added new recipe"), 200


@app.route('/my_recipes', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required()
def get_my_recipes():
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()

    query = Recipe.select().join(Users).where(Recipe.poster_id == current_user)
    recipes = []
    for recipe in query:
        recipe_data = {'Recipe ID':recipe.id}
        recipes.append(recipe_data)
    return jsonify(recipes)
```

This is the delete route that is giving me issue. I need to be able to delete a particular recipe by id. I am using peewee

```
@app.route('/delete/<int:id>', methods=['DELETE'])
@jwt_required()
def delete_recipe(id):
    current_user = get_jwt_identity()
    query = Recipe.select().join(Users).where(Recipe.poster_id == current_user)
    recipes = []
    for recipe in query:
        recipe_data = {'Recipe ID':recipe.id}
        recipes.append(recipe_data)
        
        for i in recipes:
            if i == id:
            
                del_recipe = recipe.delete_instance()
            
            
        
            return jsonify('')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no reason to iterate over the entire set of the users recipes.

```
current_user = get_jwt_identity()
query = Recipe.delete().where(
    (Recipe.poster_id == current_user.id) &
    (Recipe.id == id))
return jsonify({'result': query.execute()})
```

Comment: i got an error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: OK, then `(Recipe.poster_id == current_user)` - I assumed the current_user was some object, not just the ID.

Comment: It worked like magic. i really appreciate the effort. I am still new to the language but its getting better. Please how do I make my current user an object so it can hold all the details of the user. I tried doing that but I could only get the userid.